# pi4 Only 4B fails to reboot

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, raspberry-pi-os, reboot

I have a Raspberry Pi 3B and 4B. It operates 24 hours a day. Reboot once a day.
Only 4B fails to restart about once a week.
The screen goes black. The lamp on the Raspberry Pi 4B is normal, so it's not an EEPROM issue. Also, even if I delete the application I created, the restart fails.

If the restart fails, you cannot ping or ssh. The screen turns black. The display doesn't go into sleep mode, so I think it's sending some signal to HDMI

I checked var / log / message but couldn't find any issues.

If there is anything else to check, please let me know.
thank you

Answer (score 2):

A failed reboot is either due to a failure to shutdown, or a failure to start again. A watchdog should help with the failure to shutdown: simply `touch /dev/watchdog` to start a countdown if you don't use a service or `systemctl kill -s SIGSTOP watchdog.service` if you use one. Your system will then have 15 seconds until a hardware reset is triggered.

If what you have is a failure to boot, post your EEPROM config and investigate further which conditions lead to the failure (I understand it doesn't happen every time).